# TypeError: len() of unsized object when converting object to numeric

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numeric

I am working on a dataframe which has a column of the form:

allHoldingsFund['ratioBest']

```
Out[72]: 
65357                     0.0
65371                     0.0
65394       2.396777442094666
65397                     0.0
65433      0.0167993412023058
65462                     0.0
65560                     0.0
Name: ratioBest, Length: 1664, dtype: object
```

the  column is an object and i usually convert the object to a numeric value using `allHoldingsFund['ratioBest']=pd.to_numeric(allHoldingsFund['ratioBest'])`

However when I do that I get an error that I am not able to solve:

```
pd.to_numeric(allHoldingsFund['ratioBest'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/qtrinst/install/python/anaconda/envs/sx_anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-71-6f0ccaf63f24>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.to_numeric(allHoldingsFund['ratioBest'])
  File "/apps/qtrinst/install/python/anaconda/envs/sx_anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/numeric.py", line 133, in to_numeric
    coerce_numeric=coerce_numeric)
  File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1111, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

How can I solve this issue please?

Comment: How working `allHoldingsFund['ratioBest']=pd.to_numeric(allHoldingsFund['ratioBest'], errors='coerce')` ?

Comment: @jezrael Thanks. It is working fine. However, it is still an object. it is not converted into float which makes the column not usable for other purposes

Comment: So `print (allHoldingsFund['ratioBest'].dtype)` return again `object` ?

Comment: yes  `print (allHoldingsFund['ratioBest'].dtype)
object`     i can also tell from this operation which does not work  `np.where(allHoldingsFund['ratioBest']>1,1,0)`

Comment: For me it working nice

Answer (score 0):

For me working nice parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert no numeric to `NaN`s:

```
allHoldingsFund = pd.DataFrame({'ratioBest':[['123'], '123', 'aaa']})

allHoldingsFund['ratioBest'] = pd.to_numeric(allHoldingsFund['ratioBest'], errors='coerce')
print (allHoldingsFund)
   ratioBest
0        NaN
1      123.0
2        NaN

print (allHoldingsFund['ratioBest'].dtypes)
float64
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `to_numeric` converts argument to a numeric type.
The error which you get `len() of unsized object` is only when calculating something like `len()` of an `int` value. So the only explanation to your error is whatever data structure you have stored the column in, either some or all of it is already stored in the form of `float` as pandas is trying to find its length and getting the above error.

Comment: I disagree because if floats only then OP should get `Name: ratioBest, Length: 1664, dtype: float64`, not `Name: ratioBest, Length: 1664, dtype: object` and also if only floats `pd.to_numeric` working nice. In my opinion it seems bug.

Comment: the column `allHoldingsFund['ratioBest']` is created by using np.where . Basically if values exists then i take the ratio of those values if they do not exist i just set the ratio to zero. `allHoldingsFund['ratioBest']=np.where (if values exist, take the ratio, 0 )`

Comment: @jezrael  why bug?

Comment: @SBad - Because weird error. My solution not working?

Comment: My answer was solely based on your stack trace and here you go, that's your problem: `I just set the ratio to zero.`. Pandas is definitely trying to find the length of each element and that is the error caused when you try to find the length of `int 0`. Try making it `'0'` and you should be good to go.

Comment: try converting everything to `str` and test it

Comment: @Ishan  excuse my ignorance but if I do  `allHoldingsFund['ratioBest']=np.where (if values exist, take the ratio, '0' )` the resulting column will be a mix of string  (due to '0') and float (due to integer division)  right?  why not replace 0 by 0.0 to make it float as opposed to '0'

Comment: my answer tells you the cause of the error. Testing with different values debugging the root of the problem is your job  until you get a working sample. The next thing to do is to reason out why is this working and why it wasn't earlier. BTW if all your data is float before hand and you know it already, no reason to even use the function `to_numeric`.

Comment: i totally get your point. I knew my data was float but i was still confused as to why the column type was an object .thats why i was using `to_numeric`.  then you pointed at the issue of using int and float in one column   ...still investigating how to fix this by replacing 0